# How to change the property in my UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to change the isEditable property in my HomeCollectionViewCell controller when I long press my HomeCollectionView. However, I can only set them in cellForItemAtIndexPath method. I want to set them in handleLongPress method.

here is my property in HomeCollectionViewCell

```
var isEditable:Bool = false {
    didSet {
        updateUI()
    }
}

func updateUI(){
    videoImage.image! = videoInformation.featuredImage
    videoImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    videoTitle.text! = videoInformation.title
    if isEditable {
        deleteButton.hidden = false
    } else {
        deleteButton.hidden = true
    }
}
```

here is my handleLongPress method:

```
func editVideoFiles(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began{
        let p:CGPoint = sender.locationInView(self.collectionView)
        let index: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(p)!
        if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index) {
            //cell is the UICollectionViewCell, I do not know how to set the isEditable property by this.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```
func editVideoFiles(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began{
        let p:CGPoint = sender.locationInView(self.collectionView)
        let index: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(p)!
        if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index) as? HomeCollectionViewCell {
            cell.isEditable = true.
        }
    }
}
```

**WHY IT WORKS:**

Your `isEditable` property only exists in your HomeCollectionViewCell class (because you defined it in there).

You can access a property from another class by calling it on an instance of that other class. You'd think `class.property` would work (which amounts here to:`HomeCollectionViewCell.isEditable`).

But you need to call the property on the INSTANCE of a class, which means `HomeCollectionViewCell.isEditable` won't work. You need to first create an instance of the class:

`let cell: HomeCollectionViewCell`

So you can do:

`cell.isEditable`

Therefore, by casting your `cell` (which is originally created as a CollectionViewCell) as a HomeCollectionViewCell, you can now call `isEditable`on `cell` and do:

`cell.isEditable = true`

Comment: Thanks! But I want to set the property of all my visible cells. When I use for cell in collectionView.visibleCells(), I cannot cast cell into HomeCollectionViewCell, Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I have solved that problem, just say             for cell in (self.collectionView.visibleCells() as? [HomeCollectionViewCell])!

Answer (score -1):

You have to cast cell to HomeCollectionViewCell, then you will be able to use your property.

```
if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index) as? HomeCollectionViewCell {
    cell.isEditable = true;
}
```